# C++ reading an remote fie using boost.?

Tags: c++

I need to read an remote file using c++,i am trying to read an remote robots.txt file with an example ...

eg

```
www.google.co.in/robots.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Urdl:
http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/index.html
Not in boost (at least yet), but written by the author of Boost.Asio Christopher Kohlhoff. So expect the same quality. I have used it, and it did the job easily and very well.

Comment: ya i found it was usefull but i struck in istalling it... if i run bjam`/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:270: in find-jamfile from module project
error: Unable to load Jamfile.
error: Could not find a Jamfile in directory '/usr/include/boost'.
error: Attempted to find it with pattern '[Bb]uild.jam [Jj]amfile.v2 [Jj]amfile [Jj]amfile.jam'.
`

Comment: Where have you run bjam from? It should be run in urdl-0.1/build directory.

Comment: raj@raj-laptop:~/Desktop/urdl-0.1/build$ bjam
error: Unable to find file or target named
error:     '/boost/date_time//boost_date_time'
error: referred from project at
error:     '.'

Comment: Create a file ~/Desktop/jamroot with the following content (without quotes): "use-project /boost : /path/to/boost ;", where /path/to/boost is the path of the boost's root directory (that is the directory which contains the top-level Jamroot of boost package). I don't know if and how it's possible to make it work with system-preinstalled boost. If the latter isn't possible you might want to download and untar boost yourself, then use the produced directory in place of '/path/to/boost' in ~/Desktop/jamroot .

Comment: smells like it is not maintained any more... Cannot install neither as a library  nor as a header-only library.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp